# passing named_scope as argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reusing a controller method and I need to change the scope as required.

I have stored the scope name in a session and would like to be able to do the following.

```
if params[:scope_name]
  session[:submission_scope_name] = params[:scope_name]
else
  session[:submission_scope_name] = "allSubs"
end


@search = Submission.session[:submission_scope_name].search do
          ...
end
```

The code above is giving me  the following error message:

```
undefined method `session' for #<Class:0x00000002ad7df0>
```

Is there any way of passing a named_scope as an argument?

Comment: Why are calling session on `Submission` class? it should be called on the controller object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this from a security standpoint: a malicious user could make a poorly-formed submission_scope that you'll just be sending straight to `Submission`.

That said, you're looking for the method `send` here. Try this instead:

```
Submission.send(session[:submission_scope_name].to_sym).search
```

`send` will try to call a method on that object named whatever symbol you passed in. You can read more about it [in the Ruby core docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send), but ultimately doing that would allow you to send whatever named scopes to `Submission` you want.